# How can I auto resize all the column tables in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a writer on a website. And I am copying some tables from another website for a presentation. However when I copy they look like this:

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk8ys.png)

And I changed

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
```

to

this

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
```

[After the resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUPXg.png)

And it worked. However I cannot do this manually because it includes over 2000 tables. How can I resize them automatically? I'm a newbie and don't know much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **Find and replace text** functionallity in your editor. In VS code and Notepad++ this can be found using `CTRL+H`.

As the search string, fill in the values of the class from the table that needs to be resized, in your case that would be `col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12`. As the replacement string, fill in the new class values, that would be `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12`. Look for a button that says **Replace all occurrences** or **Replace all**.

Remember to make a backup of your file when doing these kind of things.

Comment: Tried it but nothing occurred. The problem is still continuing.

Comment: Please be more elaborate, I can't help you this way. What do you mean with "nothing occurred"? Were there no search results? Are the 2000 tables you mentioned in one file or in multiple files?

Comment: all the tables are in one page. I changed to col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 but nothing changed